# how to access Dynamic scope returned in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, dynamic-scope

I have a requirement – single angular js function to return the scope variable dynamically based on one of the input parameter to the function. For controller function, I found some example on how to return dynamic scope like

$scope[attributeId] = data.response; (attributeId is an input parameter, data.response is an array)

Question is how to use such scope variable in HTML? I have a select control like this which will populate a dropdown with the values retuned in the scope, what should be specified as model and option in such case.

```
<button ng-click="getAttributeValue(getProductsModel,p.attributeId, $event)">Get Attribute Value</button>
<select data-ng-model="attributeModel" 
    data-ng-options="a for a in attributeResponse">
    <option value="">-- Select Value --</option>
</select>
```

An example would really help.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign it to `$scope.attributeId`. After that, you can populate it using the `ng-options` directive.

Now I don't know how your data structure is, so here's an example with cars.

The imaginary `array`:

```
$scope.cars = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Ford'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Mercedes'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'BMW'
    },
]
```

And the `<select>` element with the populated cars:

```
<select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="car.name for car in cars">
```

Now you can access the chosen option using `$scope.selectedOption`.

Comment: Not exactly. The same function will be called multiple time with different input, each time it will return an array with different data which need to persisted. Each scope like $scope[101], $scope[201], $scope[301] to be bound to different dropdown.